# Moving downhill a patch variable while maintaining a global direction

Tags: netlogo

I am building a dispersal model in a landscape with different landcover types: urban, forest, residential etc. Each one of these landcover types has a resistance-to-movement patch variable and they are found in clusters of patches:

urban - 4 + random-float 1.0

residential - 9 + random-float 1.0

forest - 1 + random-float 1.0.

I would like my turtles to move downhill the resistance values from one forest patch cluster to another. The issue I am having however, is that because the resistance values are not distributed in a gradient, the turtles will stay put if the resistance of its neighbours is the same or move backwards away from the forest patches if the resistance is lower in that direction.

Most models in the model library that use the downhill/uphill functions have gradient landscapes such as mountains, but mine are randomly distributed.

How can I get my turtles to move downhill while also maintaining a global direction towards the forest patches so that they do not move backwards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That seems rather like a modelling problem than like a Netlogo problem to me.
How would you like the turtles to move, if they have visited all forest patches in that cluster?

Two ideas:

- they move to the patch with the smallest resistance from all neighbor patches, that are closer to their destination, e.g. with `min-one-of`

```
    face destination   ; destination is a patch
                       ; could be a global variable set in setup
    let candidates (patch-set patch-right-and-ahead 30 1
                              patch-left-and-ahead 30 1 
                              patch-ahead 1)
    move-to min-one-of candidates [value]  ; turtle moves to the candidate patch with the smallest "value"
```

- or, if they have knowledge of the whole landscape, they could use a path search algorithm such as A* in order to minimize the sum of resistance on their path.

Comment: Hi @Lena, thank you for the reply! I would like the turtles to move to the lowest resistance of their neighbor patches while maintaining a global destination towards the forest patches. They would only have local knowledge of their neighbor patches and not of the whole landscape. Is there a way to use the min-one-of function while also ensuring that the global direction is maintained?